Does electroweak theory have mass gap (not just Higgs mechanism)?
I am extremely confused by seemingly contradictory statements.
In this PE answer, the electroweak sector in the Standard Model does NOT have a mass gap (or at least not observed). In fact, the gauge group for electroweak theory (before Higgs mechanism) is $SU(2) \times U(1)$, so it is NOT a simple Lie group. This is in accordance with the statement of the mass gap problem, which only deals with simple compact Lie groups.
However, this arXiv link seems to imply that the electroweak theory has a mass gap (in addition to the Higgs mechanism).
These are blatantly contradictory and I am totally at a loss....Could anyone please tell me what is correct?

A Higgsed non-Abelian gauge theory has two would-be scales, a spontaneous symmetry breaking scale, and a confinement scale determined by the running of the coupling, analogous to $\Lambda_{QCD}$. Whichever of these scales has higher energy is what is actually realized, but in both scenarios there are massive particles with pretty much the same low energy particle content. There is no sharp phase transition between Higgs and confining `phases' (see e.g. Fradkin and Shenker (1979) ).
In fact there is a confining version of the standard model that agrees with low energy particle phenomenology and only disagrees with experiment at higher energy. See e.g. Abbott and Farhi (`Are the Weak Interactions Strong?', Phys Lett B, 69 (1981)).
So to briefly answer your question, the Standard model with or without Higgsing does not have a mass gap in the sense that there is a massless photon associated with the $U(1)$ part of the group, but the non-Abelian bosons and so on do get a mass and are quite similar in both scenarios.

"non-Abelian bosons and so on do get a mass" => does it refer to mass or mass gap? Gluons are massless but known to have a mass gap (=confinement). $Z$ and $W$ bosons gain mass via Higgs mechanism. You are saying that $Z$ and $W$ bosons also have mass gap "regardless of" Higgs mechanism?

Yes, the Z and W bosons have a mass gap regardless of the Higgs mechanism. There are three SU(2) color neutral spin 1 particles that can be thought of as a confined bound state of two Higgs particles from the confinement point of view and the Z and W bosons from the Higgs point of view. See the paper by Abbott and Farhi if you'd like more details (you can get a version without a paywall on google scholar)
